# com.android.volley.clientError Android Studio Error

Tags: java, android, android-volley

When I press on the register button this error occurs.

I have installed the volley 1.1.1

[image]

this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etEmail, etPassword;
    private String email, password;
    private String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/login/login.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        email = password = "";
        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    }

    public void login(View view) {
        email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(!email.equals("")&&!password.equals("")){
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.equals("success")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Success.class);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    } else if (response.equals("failure")) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Login Id/Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
                protected Map<String, String> getParms() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> parms = new HashMap<>();
                    parms.put("email",email);
                    parms.put("password", password);
                    return parms;

                }

            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fields can not be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: The image isn't on your question. Can you copy and paste the error that you get ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have added an image to be clear for you guys

Comment: Instead of just providing a `Toast`, you should really log the exception stack trace and check out the logcat to see what it says.